# JQuery each() failure loops

Tags: jquery, each

I try to write a loop to wrap all img on the picture via Jquery:

```
var $csstring = "div.article_column a img";
$($csstring).each(
  function() {    
        $($csstring).parent().wrap("<div class='dropshadow'></div>");
 });
```

and I receive this:

```
<div class="dropshadow">
    <div class="dropshadow">
        <div class="dropshadow">
            <div class="dropshadow">>
                <div class="dropshadow">
                    <a target="_blank" href="/ferdynand.jpg">
                        <img height="126" width="190" border="0" src="aae7dda0d83bf7df21ce6f834db8228a.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I mean that was 5 pictures with the same css, Can somebody help me?

Comment: It's minor, but the convention is to use `$` at the start of a variable name if it will be assigned a jquery object.  In this case `$csstring` is a string variable, so it may be confusing to have the `$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
$($csstring).each(function() {
    $(this).parent().wrap('<div class="dropshadow"></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without looping

```
// this contains an array of elements
var $csstring = $("div.article_column a img"); 

// this will wrap all objects with your html
$csstring.wrap("<div class='dropshadow'></div>");
```

Note: You need to wrap your string with $() to use the variable as a jquery object.

**Edit:**
If you want to access a specific node in the array...

```
var $firstElement = $($csstring[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `$csstring` to `this` within the loop function:

```
var $csstring = "div.article_column a img";
$($csstring).each(
    function() {    
        $(this).parent().wrap("<div class='dropshadow'></div>");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even need each.  Just do this:

```
$("div.article_column a img").parent().wrap("<div class='dropshadow'></div>");
```